# WPF 3D Editor which look like 3DSMAX

Tags: wpf, xaml, editor, 3d

Is there any source for a WPF 3D editor (4 viewport : perspective,front,top,left)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

What you're talking about is [Blender](http://www.blender.org) with [XAML Exporter](http://xamlexporter.codeplex.com).

Comment: In fact, i talk about an inside editor (much simple than blender) to let users move some 3D objects

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any complete WPF open source editor, but these links should give you the info needed to create one yourself :

WPF Perspective 3D:
http://www.odewit.net/ArticleList.aspx?key=Perspective3D&lang=en

Helix 3D Toolkit:
http://helixtoolkit.codeplex.com/